# Mysterious symbolic links: ln -s creating 'ghost' files

Tags: unix, directory, symlink

I have a directory with a couple files. I simply wish to create a symbolic link in my home directory that leads to this directory like so:

```
ln -s dir ~/.dir
```

Everything works fine and runs properly, but when I run `cd ~/.dir` it gives:

```
cd: no such file or directory: .dir
```

This sounds pretty basic, but when I run `ls -a ~` the `.dir` directory appears in the output to exist! Even stranger, when I run `rm -r ~/.dir` it is removed from the directory normally (wasn't in `ls` output anymore).

### Attempts

I tried creating the directory before creating the symlink:

```
$ mkdir ~/.dir
$ ln -s dir ~/.dir
```

Only to get:

```
$ cd
$ cd .dir
$ ls
dir
$ cd dir
cd: too many levels of symbolic links: dir
```

Comment: better use absolute paths as the source of the symbolic link. I guess you did not run the first `ln` command in the directory you believe ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch a format like `ln -s $HOME/subdir/dir $HOME/.dir` seems to work fine.

Comment: Read [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [symlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html)